# Saving a SQL file that queries multiple databases

Tags: sql-server

In MS SQL Server, you can create and run a query against multiple databases using Registered Servers. It is also possible to save a query to a .sql file in order to have ready access to it in the future. However, I can't seem to save a query that was designed to run against multiple databases in such a way that when it is opened, it reconnects to the multiple databases again. I'm trying to avoid having to open a new query through the Registered Servers feature and then manually have to copy the query into the new tab (call me lazy). Surely there's a way to do this in one step.

Edit: When I open a file that was saved from a tab connected to multiple databases, the tab does not connect to a database. Attempting to connect by [right-click]+Connections, the options are disabled and I cannot connect to any database, much less multiple databases.

Answer (score 1):

Select the registered server group and then click File-->Open-->File from the menu bar (or press CTRL-O). Open the script file and it will open in a new multi-server query window. No copy/paste needed.

Comment: That would only make since, but it doesn't seem to work that way. When I open the file, it opens in a new, non-multi window.

Comment: @RandyDavis, what version of SSMS are you using? When I select a registered server group, press CTRL-O, and open the script file in the open file dialog, the script opens in a new multi-server query window. I'm using SSMS v18.8.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, for your comment. However, mine does not seem to work like yours. I'm running v18.8, also. Maybe there is a setting that is governs this. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: Hmm...I don't recall changing a related setting.  Do you have any 3rd party add-ins installed?